# Why are virtual addresses so big in my C program?

Tags: c, virtual-memory

I recently learned about virtual memory and paging and that compilers only generate virtual addresses starting by 1 and simply counting upwards. I thought I'd test this and wrote the short C progam below that instantiates a global variable and prints it's address, expecting a very small value, since the CPU only sees the virtual addresses, but instead I get **4247584**. What is going on here, are my assumptions wrong? And if possible, what would be a program that shows virtual addresses being generated from 1 up?

My program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int x = 0;

int main(){
    printf("%d\n", &x);
    return 0;
}
```

(I'm using gcc 4.8.1 on Windows 10)

Comment: Correct format to print out the address: `printf("%p\n", &x);`

Comment: @wired: A correct way to print an address is `printf("%p\n", (void *) &x);`. Passing `int *` for `%p` is not defined by the C standard; it should be converted to `void *`.

Comment: In addition to tofro answer, I would mention that modern OS deliberately don't assign virtual address close to 0. This is to make sure that dereferencing `NULL`, even with some small offset, will always generate a segmentation fault, easier to debug.

Comment: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20141003-00/?p=43923

Comment: "compilers only generate virtual addresses starting by 1 and simply counting upwards."  That is just not true, whoever told you that is wrong.

Answer (score 6):

The actual *value* of a virtual address is relatively non-essential (well, because it's virtual). There's nothing "wasted" when it doesn't start at 0. The only precondition for address values is that the program, data and all its associated shared libraries actually fit into the value-space.

For security reasons, however, it makes sense to allocate the various code and data areas of a process in virtual address space in a way non-reproducible by a potential attacker (makes code injection attacks at fixed addresses virtually[sic] impossible), that is why modern operating systems allocate virtual address space values for a program *randomly*.

On some operating systems like Linux you may be able to switch off virtual [address space layout randomization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization) and thus make it reproducible. Addresses will most probably still not start at zero, because libraries and startup code will most likely occupy addresses lower than your own program.